# Can USB device be aware of in-game death?

Tags: game-state

I intend to design a peripheral that changes state (in this case, LED color) in response to software state (ideally, player death in-game). I have adequate experience in manufacturing design, but not on the driver/software side of things. Before I try to contract out the driver/software need, I'd like an objective opinion from those who know (GameDev SE) whether or not this is even possible.

***Potential Use-case:*** player in Source-engine game dies >> peripheral lighting changes from green to red for duration of dead period. Player respawns, lighting returns to green state.

Are there hooks in modern engines that would allow a USB peripheral to be aware of this sort of specific game condition? We don't want to require customers to install and run a background process to monitor state. That's way too intrusive.

Comment: I don't think that most USB sticks have different colours of lights, let alone you being able to turn them on and off, unfortunately.

Comment: @Lolums - as mentioned, the physical engineering is not in question. I want to know if there is any game-state specific software feedback available to a USB controller related to being killed. We have rumble capability now in some games, so that's a general option, but that isn't as specific as "you died" or "you jumped" and so on.

Comment: Oh. If all else fails, you could have a tiny CPU on the USB, which could keep checking the value of a file to change the lights.

Comment: That would be a no-go. It would mean 1) that the file has to be on a fixed location on the user's filesystem. and 2) even while the game is not running the device is active. If you can configure 1 and override 2, it means you are able to send a signal to the device (which is possible by USB) so use that mechanic for setting the device state.

Comment: Even worse: It would mean having USB devices that are capable of reading files from the computer, so, plug in a USB stick and suddenly I have your passwords copied to it.

Answer (score 2):

The PS4 controller has a lightbar. It is used in (for example) Towerfall Ascension to indicate player id (red for player one, blue for player 2 etc.) and Transistor (mimics the swords speech). Those games are made in C#/Monogame. I also understood that Unity, provided you have the PS4 license, can access the lightbar. So there is definitely a possibility to do what you're looking for.

If I understand correctly, you plan to design your own device. USB is a bidirectional so you can send a datastream to a device. So it is up to you to design the device to accept a stream and interpret the meaning of the data being sent. 
So in your example, the code should sent an RGBA code to the USB device. The Device reads the value and sets the color (RGB) and uses the Alpha as brightness value.

There are many libraries out there for languages to send and receive data to a USB device. So a Google query may point you to the language of your choice.

Comment: This would require the USB device falsely presenting itself as a DualShock 4 gamepad, so that the game even attempts to set its lightbar, correct? This may run afoul of Sony's intellectual property protections. If you only need it for a prototype, [there's a good breakdown of the HID report structure the DS4 uses here](http://eleccelerator.com/wiki/index.php?title=DualShock_4#Report_Structure)

Comment: I only provided the Dualshock 4 gamepad as an example that his use-case technically works (and has been done). The original poster states that he wants to create a device by his own design. That device should represent itself for what it is (could be a generic HID) with an API of it's own to send and receive messages. For a device of his own design and own API no breach of Sony's IP is required (IANAL though).

Comment: Good point, but then the games would have to use this new API in order for it to work. We wouldn't see Towerfall or Transistor changing the colour of the new USB peripheral unless those games were patched to explicitly look for and interact with it, the way they do for the DS4's light bar. I just wanted to clarify for readers that a game supporting a particular light peripheral doesn't imply it will necessarily support any other without modification.

Comment: Indeed, as far as I am aware the lightbar is not part of a generic controller API. So I would guess that Towerfall supports this on real PS4 controllers only. For the OP, his device would require support by the gamedevelopers.

Comment: Any idea whether there's a generic API for light-up enthusiast keyboards? Or is that all vendor-specific too?

Comment: They seem vendor specific, so far I haven't been able to find any.